# Unable to fabricate Twitter::Tweet from twitter gem using Fabrication gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, fabrication-gem

I'm trying to fabricate Twitter::Tweet class from Twitter gem. And I got this error

```
undefined method `id' for #<Fabrication::Schematic::Runner:0x00000102da7c28>
```

Here's my Fabricator.

```
Fabricator(:twitter_tweet, from: 'Twitter::Tweet', class_name: 'Twitter::Tweet') do
    id "1"
    text "tweet"
    created_at Time.now
    user {
        id "created_by_social_id"
        name "name"
        location "location"
    }
    entites {
        user_mentions nil
    }
end
```

But I could create it manually like this.

```
tweet = Twitter::Tweet.new(:id => "1", 
      :created_at => Time.now.to_s,
      :text => "text",
      :user => {
        :id => "created_by_social_id",
        :name => "name",
        :location => "location"
      }, 
      :entities => {:user_mentions => user_mentions})
```

Did I miss anything obvious?

Comment: Are you sue you have an `id` method in `Tweet.new`? You're trying to create a new tweet, not an ActiveRecord object. Can you clarify whether you're trying to create a tweet or database entry?

Comment: I'm just trying to create a new tweet. I'm trying to create an object from this Gem https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/lib/twitter/tweet.rb

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the Trello gem. I suspect the "id" you're stuck on is the one inside `user`... 

Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Twitter**

I think you're getting confused of how to [use the `Twitter` gem to create Tweets](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/examples/Update.md):

```
client.update("I'm tweeting with @gem!")
```

This is how you can create a new tweet. This is based on the idea you've already [initialized an object](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/examples/Configuration.md) & associated with the variable `client`:

```
#config/initializers/twitter.rb
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key    = "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY"
  config.consumer_secret = "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
end
```

---

**Code**

Although not a direct answer to using `fabrication`, I would suggest you have to adapt your syntax to accommodate the loading of this gem (connecting to the Twitter API), and then use `fabrication` to sort it out